# Chrome compilation error - FIle name too long

Tags: google-chrome

I'm following the official `Chrome` documentation and I'd like to compile my own version. Unfortunately at compile time one of the filename is too long as shown below:

```
➜  src git:(ccbeb246d2) autoninja -C out/asan chrome                                                                                                                                                                                                             
ninja: Entering directory `out/asan'
[95/38400] RUST(BIN) clang_x64_for_rust_host_build_tools/compiler_builtins_compiler_builtins_vunknown_build_script
FAILED: clang_x64_for_rust_host_build_tools/compiler_builtins_compiler_builtins_vunknown_build_script 
"python3" "../../build/rust/rustc_wrapper.py" --rustc=../../third_party/rust-toolchain/bin/rustc --depfile=clang_x64_for_rust_host_build_tools/compiler_builtins_compiler_builtins_vunknown_build_script.d --rsp=clang_x64_for_rust_host_build_tools/compiler_builtins_compiler_builtins_vunknown_build_script.rsp -- -Clinker="../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++" --crate-name compiler_builtins_compiler_builtins_vunknown_build_script ../../third_party/rust-toolchain/lib/rustlib/src/rust/vendor/compiler_builtins-0.1.103/build.rs --crate-type bin --cfg=backtrace_in_libstd -Zforce-unstable-if-unmarked --cfg=feature=\"compiler-builtins\" --cfg=feature=\"core\" --cfg=feature=\"rustc-dep-of-std\" --cfg=feature=\"weak-intrinsics\" --edition=2018 -Cforce-unwind-tables=yes -Crelocation-model=pic -Coverflow-checks=on -Cdefault-linker-libraries -Zdep-info-omit-d-target -Zmacro-backtrace -Zremap-cwd-prefix=. --color=always --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -Cembed-bitcode=no --cfg cr_rustc_revision=\"df0295f07175acc7325ce3ca4152eb05752af1f2-1-llvmorg-18-init-12938-geb1d5065\" -Copt-level=3 --cap-lints=allow -Dunsafe_op_in_unsafe_fn -Dwarnings -Funsafe_code --sysroot=clang_x64_for_rust_host_build_tools/prebuilt_rustc_sysroot --emit=dep-info=clang_x64_for_rust_host_build_tools/compiler_builtins_compiler_builtins_vunknown_build_script.d,link -o clang_x64_for_rust_host_build_tools/compiler_builtins_compiler_builtins_vunknown_build_script LDFLAGS -fuse-ld=lld -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--build-id -fPIC -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--icf=all -Wl,--color-diagnostics -Wl,--undefined-version -Wl,--no-call-graph-profile-sort -m64 -no-canonical-prefixes -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,--as-needed -nostdlib++ --sysroot=../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot -rdynamic -pie -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Werror  RUSTENV OUT_DIR=../../../../../../../../out/asan/clang_x64_for_rust_host_build_tools/gen/build/rust/std/rules/compiler_builtins_compiler_builtins_vunknown_build_script CFG_DISABLE_UNSTABLE_FEATURES=0 STD_ENV_ARCH=x86_64 CARGO_PKG_AUTHORS=Jorge\ Aparicio\ \<japaricious@gmail.com\> CARGO_PKG_VERSION=0.1.103 CARGO_PKG_NAME=compiler_builtins CARGO_PKG_DESCRIPTION=Compiler\ intrinsics\ used\ by\ the\ Rust\ compiler.\ Also\ available\ for\ other\ targets\ if\ necessary\! CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR=/home/fabio/progetti/chromium/src/third_party/rust-toolchain/lib/rustlib/src/rust/vendor/compiler_builtins-0.1.103
error: could not write output to clang_x64_for_rust_host_build_tools/compiler_builtins_compiler_builtins_vunknown_build_script.compiler_builtins_compiler_builtins_vunknown_build_script.479f9f1abd4ef2c-cgu.4.rcgu.o: File name too long

error: aborting due to 1 previous error

[111/38400] RUST clang_x64_for_rust_host_build_tools/obj/third_party/rust/clap_builder/v4/lib/libclap_builder-clap_builder-4.rlib
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
➜  src git:(ccbeb246d2)
```

Any idea on how I could have a shorter path?

Thanks

I tried to use the official docs from [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/linux/build_instructions.md#Install) but nothing. I cannot compile it